Присоединить к таблице сумму значений последних ненулевых строк за прошлый периоды
Есть Таблица 1 формата:



Provider
Date




001
01.03.2000


001
01.04.2000



(поставщиков > 1)
В один месяц на 1,у поставщика может быть только одна дата, месяца могут пропускаться
и Таблица 2 формата:



Provider
Contract
Date
Sum




001
111111
01.01.2000
100


001
111111
01.03.2000
150


001
222222
01.01.2000
200


001
222222
01.04.2000
250



(> 1 поставщиков, > 1 договоров у каждого поставщика)
Как можно соединить вторую с первой, чтобы был появился у первой результирующие столбец суммы по поставщику и договору. Если дата пропускается, мы берём последнюю известную дату
Например:



Provider
Date
Result




001
01.03.2000
150 + 200


001
01.04.2000
150 + 250



По контракту 111111 на 03 мес 150, по 222222 последняя известная сумма 200
По контракту 111111 на 04 мес последняя известная сумма 150, по 222222 250

Выглядит так, будто в таблице 2 остатки по договору и нужно посчитать сумму остатков по всем договорам поставщика на даты. При этом брать последние известные остатки. Покажите, что Вы пытались сделать, каков ход мысли.

@ValNik идея есть такая, что считать для каждой комбинации поставщик дата из первой таблицы считать rownumber для каждого контракта в обратном порядке и считать сумму, где rownumber = 1. С реализацией сложновато

Пример



provider
date




001
2000-03-01


001
2000-04-01






provider
contract
date
summa




001
111111
2000-01-01
100


001
111111
2000-03-01
150


001
222222
2000-01-01
200


001
222222
2000-04-01
250



Присоединяем к каждой строке таблицы1 все строки данного поставщика из таблицы2 и нумеруем по убыванию даты в пределах каждого договора.
select *
  ,row_number()over(partition by t1.provider,t1.date,t2.contract
                order by t2.date desc)rn
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.provider=t1.provider
  and t2.date<=t1.date
order by t1.provider,t1.date,t2.date




provider
date
provider
contract
date
summa
rn




001
2000-03-01
001
111111
2000-01-01
100
2


001
2000-03-01
001
222222
2000-01-01
200
1


001
2000-03-01
001
111111
2000-03-01
150
1


001
2000-04-01
001
222222
2000-01-01
200
2


001
2000-04-01
001
111111
2000-01-01
100
2


001
2000-04-01
001
111111
2000-03-01
150
1


001
2000-04-01
001
222222
2000-04-01
250
1



итоговое суммирование
select provider,date,sum(summa)summa
  ,string_agg(cast(summa as varchar),'+')s
from(
  select t1.provider,t1.date,t2.summa,t2.date rdate
    ,row_number()over(partition by t1.provider,t1.date,t2.contract
                      order by t2.date desc)rn
  from table1 t1
  left join table2 t2 on t2.provider=t1.provider
         and t2.date<=t1.date
)a
where rn=1
group by provider,date
order by provider,date




provider
date
summa
s




001
2000-03-01
350
150+200


001
2000-04-01
400
150+250



fiddle

Все работает, спасибо
